# Is there any way that i can see PhotoScroller in Swift?

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, uiimageview

Apple has released many great tutorial at WWDC 2010.So,I want to learn PhotoScroller which is one of them included photo scrolling with zoom feature.But most of the code are in Objc.So,is there any way that i can learn it in Swift?

Here is the link to PhotoScroller :

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/PhotoScroller/Introduction/Intro.html

Any code help or example same like this is appreciated.Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this one. It is based on Apple's PhotoScroller demo, added some extra features and was written in Swift
https://github.com/huynguyencong/ImageScrollView

Answer (score 2):

You can find the Swift version of PhotoScroller App at the following link:
https://github.com/villyg/PhotoSlideShow-Swift